# Send requests and receive answers between mitmproxy and upstream

Tags: http, https, http-proxy, mitmproxy

I'm trying to develop an addon in mitmproxy that will analyze some HTTPS/HTTP responses from the endpoint server/website and react to specific responses received.
I would then block the response from accessing the client, and instead send a GET request from mitmproxy to the endpoint server, and then receive a response from that same endpoint server, then analyze it, send back a GET request without the previous response getting to the client, and once I get a correct answer from the endpoint, I would forward it to the client.

In other words I want to implement this :

```
Client           Mitmproxy        CorporateProxy       Endpoint Server/Website [Internet]
GET_Request1 --> GET_Request1 --> GET_Request1  -----> GET_Request1
                 Answer1      <-- Answer1       <----- Answer1
                 GET_Request2 --> GET_Request2  -----> GET_Request2
                 Answer2      <-- Answer2       <----- Answer2
                 GET_Request3 --> GET_Request3  -----> GET_Request3
Answer3     <--  Answer3      <-- Answer3       <----- Answer3
GET_Request4 --> GET_Request4 --> GET_Request4  -----> GET_Request4
Answer4     <--  Answer4      <-- Answer4       <----- Answer4
[etc.]
```

Notice I'm using the upstream mode as I'm behind a corporate HTTP proxy server that has its own SSL certificate, so mitmproxy is very useful to decode the traffic here by posing as a CA authority behind the client with self signed SSL certificates.

I don't see in the documentation how one would "generate" a novel GET request from a mitmproxy addon using the API provided. I mostly see addons that modify requests/responses, so I'm unsure how to do it properly.

Since mitmproxy has already a HTTP connection to the endpoint, it *seems* (maybe I'm wrong) redundant to use e.g. urllib3 to generate those GET requests (adding a new dependency), and beside, I need the responses to the GET requests to go through mitmproxy.

TL;DR How do I generate a completely new GET request with existing mitmproxy facilities, a request that is upstream of the client, which will be answered by a response that will not reach the client?

Comment: What you want is not possible with HTTP 1.x. The http protocol only allows one response per request. Everything else won't work just because the client will not be able to process it. So it is not a question how to extend Mitmproxy but what client you use. With HTTP2 there are more flexibility and to my knowledge multiple responses are possible but again the client have to support/expect that and of course have to use a HTTP2 capable !ibrary.

Comment: I don't see how I break the one request one response principle even in HTTP1. The client sends a GET and still receives a response, (sends GET_Request1, receives Answer3 just like nothing happened). I forgot to put GET_Request4 line if that's what you're referring too, just edited, my bad.

Comment: My comment was based on your diagram before you updated it. It clearly showed two responses to one request. Now it has been changed.